# Proper implementation of Repository Pattern using IQueryables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building a Repository layer for my MVC application with methods like GetObject, UpdateObject, DeleteObject, etc.

This is what I have now:

```
        public List<Object> GetObjects()
        {
            return _db.Objects.Where(o => o.IsArchived == false).ToList();
        }
```

But I'm wondering if it would be better to return IQueryables for lists so that the least amount of data gets sent to the client when filters are applied in the UoW or Service layers.  Would it be best to do something like this?

```
            public IQueryable<Object> GetObjects()
            {
                return _db.Objects.Where(o => o.IsArchived == false);
            }
```

Comment: yes, do that then you can chain your queries

Comment: Are you using entity framework to interact with the db yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not nice thing about returning IQueryable, is that if you ever have a different implementation of repository, say using different ORM, storing data in non-SQL database, cloud or XML file, it would be hard to implement same interface. It would be much easier to implement if you return more generic colections of domain objects. For example IEnumerable. You can always pass filtering criteria in.

The other drawback of returning IQueryable, is that it may happen, that when you actually run the query your object context may be already disposed (Depending on your implementation) or may be kept in memory longer than required.

A leaky abstraction such as IQueryable could cause problems, for example imagine you want to get some data from database and order it by Guid. If you enumerate the query by calling `ToList()` prior to sorting, you'll get different results if you do it after. The reason is that in first case the sorting will happen in .NET, but in other case it will happen in SQL which uses completely different order.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about returning IQueryable here is that you can continue to build up your query further without hitting the db. Once you call ToList it will hit the db and you can't customize your query further without hitting the database a second time.